# Access VBA “Compile Error: Label not defined”

Tags: vba, ms-access, label, defined

One of my associates has inadvertently messed up an old Access export script and we are now receiving the "Label not defined" error and I am not anywhere close to an Access guru, any help would be nice.

```
Function Macro2()
On Error GoTo Macro2_Err

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "golfexport", "ctcexport", "P:\transferdata\golfexport05052017"
    Exit Function

Macro2_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Macro2_Exit

End Function
```

The error is highlighting the top row in yellow and the "Resume Macro2_Exit" line.

Anybody have an idea as it was most likely a fat finger to backspace that killed something.

thanks

Comment: Look at your code. Where is `Macro2_Exit` defined?

Answer (score 1):

```
Resume [Label]
```

That instruction requires a *line label* to exist, so that execution can *resume* there. If the label isn't defined, there's nowhere to jump to, and the code can't compile.

If that's all there is to the procedure, you can just remove the `Resume` instruction and call it a day. If there's code between `DoCmd` and `Exit Function`, you can define the label there:

```
Macro2_Exit:
    Exit Function
Macro2_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Macro2_Exit
```

Note the use of `Err.Description` instead of the dinosaurian `Error$` string. Just a suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that you get this same error if you write `End Function` or `End Sub` under your exit label, instead of `Exit Function` or `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Nat maybe.. then again there are countless ways to make VBA fail to compile. Also did you know you can you can very legally `Exit Function` or `Exit Sub` inside a `Property`?